Как в woocommerce создать акцию Happy friday?
Суть вопроса в принципе проста, на сайте по доставке пиццы нужно какимто образом активировать опцию чтобы при заказе двух любых пицц третья определенная автоматически попадала в корзину за бесплатно, но только по пятницам например. Возможно есть уже готовые решения которые бы работали по такому расписанию, тоесть акция должна автоматически включаться только один день в неделю. Или возможно ктото уже реализовал подобное у себя на сайте какимто особым способом? Заранее спасибо!

Уверен, что есть готовые плагины. Но не факт что весь нужный функционал будет в бесплатных версиях.

Ну если он будет закрывать все поставленніе задачи то можно и купить. Это не проблема)

Ну так поищи, такие должны быть. Это будет намного быстрее, чем ждать.

В общем есть две новости:

WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing & Discounts with AI даже в лайт (бесплатной версии) может выполнять поставленную задачу. Только в полной (платной) версии можно выбрать сразу категорию акционных товаров а в лайт товары по одному. В обеих версиях даже есть настройка конкретного дня когда акция активируется.
На моем тестовом сайте почемуто созданое правило не заработало. Может конфликт с другими плагинами. Смогу проверить на чистовом сайте гдето только через неделю. Такие дела
UPD/ Сразу не разобрался в настройках. Почитал мануал на оф сайте и как результат всё заработало. Короче тема рабочая - можно брать :)


Вот видишь как продуктивней самому искать, чем ждать у моря погоды :) И молодец что поделился решением. Может кто и нагуглит.
